# Is it possible to inject an external javascript reference into the host page from a SWF?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I have a SWF advert that needs to call the Facebook API, for which I need the following single-line reference in the host HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Since I am dealing with an advert, I don't have control over the host page. I understand I can inject functions into a page (there's a good reference for this here: [http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/745/4/JavaScript-and-VBScript-Injection-in-ActionScript-3/Page1.html](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/745/4/JavaScript-and-VBScript-Injection-in-ActionScript-3/Page4.html)), but I haven't found a way to add a reference to an externally-hosted script.

Does anybody know if this can be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a SCRIPT tag dynamically to the document. You can do that by running a anonymous function through ExternalInterface:

```
var js:Array = [
'var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT")',
'script.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"',
'var head = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0]',
'head.appendChild(script)'
];
ExternalInterface.call('(function(){' + js.join(';') + '})()');
```

Comment: But how will that load the script - by the time you add it to the head, the DOM will already be complete, and the window will have finished loading, won't it?

Comment: The browser will definitely load the script. The DOM is never "complete".

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  For example, ExternalInterface.available returns true, but `ExternalInterface.call( "(function(){alert(\"hello\");})()" );` does not result in an alert being shown, and it also causes no errors (neither handled nor unhandled).  What could be the problem?